# npm package for Couch DB server

Tags: npm, couchdb

I had installed the Widows version of Apache CouchDB and it is working for me. 
Now I am looking for an npm package for CouchDB, which I can install as a node_module to my nodejs server. Is anything of that sort exists.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll want this:

[npm couchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-couchdb)

Say if you have any more problems

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried npm couchdb. But it is a client to couchdb. I am looking for a couchdb server.

Comment: Ah, I red the question too fast. The only thing I found after my googlings was http://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-couchdb.html. It allows you to install a pouchdb server via npm. Only experimental :)

Comment: Thank you. I had come across the same. But it is not recommended for a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Nano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano)

   - **minimalistic** - there is only a minimum of abstraction between you and couchdb
   - **pipes** - proxy requests from couchdb directly to your end user
   - **errors** - errors are proxied directly from couchdb: if you know couchdb you already know nano.
2. [Cradle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cradle)

   - Asynchronous javascript client for CouchDB
   - Higher-level than most other CouchDB clients (need less knowledge of CouchDB's REST API)
   - Built-in write-through caching

Comment: I was looking for an npm module for CouchDB like a PouchDB, but i think that doesn't exists. CouchDB needs its own installation.

Comment: @sreejithsasidharan there is a npm module for [PouchDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb). Install it using `$ npm install pouchdb`.

Comment: @sreejithsasidharan few minutes later, I saw that **luxas** answered with the same answer. Can you elaborate your question in more details ? Don't you looking for a CouchDB client which can connect to Apache CouchDB instance and do any operations? May be I can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not looking for a CouchDB client, but for a server instance. Im using pouchdb for keeping local data and sync with CouchDB later point. That is working perfectly.